# qdjango foreign keys

Tags: qt, orm, foreign-keys

Quick googling returned no results on how to properly use QDjango's Foreign Keys - there are functions

`QDjangoModel::foreignKey` and `QDjangoModel::setForeignKey` - but I couldn't find any good examples on how to use them in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its quite old, maybe will help someone else.. I searched for FKs in QDjango for eons and found something in [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/qdjango), there is also [nice documentation](http://doc.qdjango.org/qdjango-snapshot/index.html) with some basic examples(but no FK examples)

I create table models using QDjango in this way (also foreign keys):

```
class Role : public QDjangoModel { ... };

class User : public QDjangoModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString password READ password WRITE setPassword)
    Q_PROPERTY(Role *role READ role WRITE setRole)

    Q_CLASSINFO("name", "max_length=255")
    Q_CLASSINFO("password", "max_length=255")
    Q_CLASSINFO("role", "on_delete=cascade")


    QString mName;
    QString mPassword;
public:
    User(QObject *parent = 0);
    QString name() const { return mName; }
    void setName(QString name) { mName = name; }

    QString password() const { return mPassword; }
    void setPassword(QString pass) { mPassword = pass; }

    Role *role() const;
    void setRole(Role *role);
};
```

You can use Q_CLASSINFO to set some attributes to columns.
The foreign keys are bound in constructor and filled in role functions.

```
User::User(QObject *parent)
    : QDjangoModel(parent)
{
    setForeignKey("role", new Role(this));
}

Role *User::role() const
{
    return qobject_cast<Role *>(foreignKey("role"));
}

void User::setRole(Role *role)
{
     setForeignKey("role", role);
}
```

When you want to select using fields from fk dependant table use **two undescores** and of course use selectRelated() (which just sets some flag which is later used to produce join select) like:

```
QDjangoQuerySet<User> matched;
matched = matched.selectRelated()
            .filter(QDjangoWhere("role__rolename", QDjangoWhere::Equals, "admin"));
```

Comment: Thanks! At least it would be in one place for posterity :)